# Stepper not fully showing step upon tapping

Tags: listview, flutter, scrollable, uistepper, stepper

Whenever i tap the steps starting from nationalities and below as shown in the gif they act as follows..

[image]

i want to allow my stepper to scroll up or down to fully show every step tapped.

Tried keeping only the listview without the formblocklistener but didn't work.

This is my code:

```
return  new Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      //backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      title: new Text('Edit Your Profile'),
      flexibleSpace: Image(
        image: AssetImage('lib/assets/BackToEarth.jpg'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
      leading:  IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () {
          print(user.profilePictureName);
          Navigator.pop(context, true);
          //Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),

      //forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled
    ),
    body:FormBlocListener(
        formBloc: _simpleFormBloc,
        key: _formKey,
        onSubmitting: (context, state) {
          // Show the progress dialog
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: false,
            builder: (_) => WillPopScope(
              onWillPop: () async => false,
              child: Center(
                child: Card(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 80,
                    height: 80,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Stepper(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                steps: steps,
                type: StepperType.vertical,
                currentStep: this.currStep,
                onStepTapped: (step) {
                  setState(() {
                    currStep = step;

                  });
                },

                controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                    {VoidCallback onStepContinue, VoidCallback onStepCancel}) =>
                    Container(),
              ),
            ])
    ),

    persistentFooterButtons: <Widget>[
    _buildUploadBtn()
  ],
  );
```

Tried so many things related to physics.. any help is appreciated!